# mysql insert in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a register form where you can register your organisation and account at the same time.
But at the moment I do not know how to insert the data correctly.
Because if you want to insert the user in the table you do not know the organisation_id yet...

I have tried using `mysqli_insert_id($conn)` to get the last inserted id but that is not really practical.

I also came to the problem that if the email of the user already existed that it would still register the organisation.

At this moment I am completely lost...

Here is a sample of my table structure with some dummy data:

---

*organisations table*

```
+-----------------+--------------------+
| organisation_id | organisation_name  |
+-----------------+--------------------+
|               1 | Google             |
|               2 | Facebook           |
+-----------------+--------------------+
```

---

*users table*

```
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+
| user_id |      email       | password | organisation_id |
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+
|       1 | test@gmail.com   | *****    |       1         | 
|       2 | test@outlook.com | ******   |       2         |
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+
```

```php
         //check for existing emails for user in database
        $get_email_stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?');
        $get_email_stmt->bind_param('s', $user_email);
        $get_email_stmt->execute();
        $get_email_result = $get_email_stmt->get_result();
        $row = $get_email_result->fetch_assoc();
        //if email does not exists execute query
        if ($row['email'] == $user_email) {
           //give error email exists
           $_SESSION["exists"] = "email";
           header('Location: ../register');
        }

        //check for existing organisation name for user in database
        $get_organisation_stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `organisation_name` FROM `organisations` WHERE organisation_name = ?');
        $get_organisation_stmt->bind_param('s', $organisation_name);
        $get_organisation_stmt->execute();
        $get_organisation_result = $get_organisation_stmt->get_result();
        $row = $get_organisation_result->fetch_assoc();
        //if email does not exists execute query
        if ($row['organisation_name'] == $organisation_name) {
           //give error email exists
           $_SESSION["exists"] = "organisation";
           header('Location: ../register');
        }

        //insert organisation
        $post_organisation_stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `organisations` (organisation_name, zipcode, cityname, country, organisation_phonenumber, organisation_email, organisation_type, organisation_url, organisation_vat, agreed_to_avg) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);');
        $post_organisation_stmt->bind_param('sssssssssi', $organisation_name, $zipcode, $cityname, $country, $organisation_phonenumber, $organisation_email, $request, $organisation_url, $organisation_vat, $agreed_to_avg);

        //execute query
        if ($post_organisation_stmt->execute()) {
            $organistation_id = mysql_insert_id($conn);
            $post_organisation_stmt->close();
            //insert user
            $post_user_stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, organisation_id, hpassword, permission, agreed_to_avg) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);');
            $post_user_stmt->bind_param('sssssssi', $firstname, $lastname, $user_email, $user_phonenumber, $organisation_id, $hPassword, $permission, $agreed_to_avg);
            //execute query
            if ($post_user_stmt->execute()) {
                //succes
                $post_answer_stmt->close();
                $_SESSION["newaccount"] = "success";
                header('Location: ../login');
            } else {
                //error
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                $post_answer_stmt->close();
                $_SESSION["exists"] = "error";
                header('Location: ../register');
            }
        }
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Share the PHP code so that we could check the issue. Without seeing anything, we can't tell anything.

Comment: What do you mean by `that is not really practical.`

Comment: We also need to see the Schema for both these tables. Please add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <TableName>;` and copy/paste the output to your question for both these tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm sorry but I was using msqli '' [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp)

Comment: Then did you set the `organisation.organisation_id` column to be a autoincrement column?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem you are describing is this:

1. INSERT INTO organisation
2. Get inserted organisation id
3. INSERT INTO user
4. If email already exists, then no user is created but the organisation remains in the database.

This can be resolved by using a transaction, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php if using mysqli.

When you run both queries in a transaction, then all changes can be rolled back when an exception occurs such as a unique constraint violation for the user email.